# Call to function in header of other file undefined reference

Tags: c++, ros, catkin

First of all, I'd like to say I'm somewhat inexperienced with c++.

I am working on a project for university using catkin. In it I have 3 files (relevant to this question), **TestCode.cpp**, **RobotInfo.cpp** and **RobotInfo.h**.

And they have the following code inside of them:

`TestCode.cpp`

```
#include "RobotInfo.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ....
    Joints::size(); //first time any call goes to Joints    
    ...
}
```

`RobotInfo.h`

```
class Joints{
protected:
    static map<string, double> info;

public:
    static int size();
}
```

`RobotInfo.cpp`

```
#include "RobotInfo.h"

map<string, double > Joints::info = map<string, double>();

int Joints::size() {
    return (int) info.size();
}
```

Plus they have all been added in CMakeLists.txt.

Now everytime I try to run it I get the following error: **undefined reference to `Joints::size()'** , pointing to the line of the size() call in TestCode.cpp.

If I change the include in TestCode.cpp to #include"RobotInfo.cpp" everything works fine, but to me that kind of looks like a dirty solution.

So what I'd like to know is what could be causing this problem, I've tried solving this for hours but it seems my lack of experience is really hurting me on this one.

Also here's everything the console outputs when I build it:

```
/home/manuel/clion-2017.1.1/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/manuel/catkin_ws/src/cmake-build-debug --target testCode -- -j 4
Scanning dependencies of target testCode
[ 50%] Building CXX object team1/CMakeFiles/testCode.dir/src/TestCode.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../devel/lib/team1/testCode
CMakeFiles/testCode.dir/src/TestCode.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/manuel/catkin_ws/src/team1/src/TestCode.cpp:32: undefined reference to `Joints::size()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
team1/CMakeFiles/testCode.dir/build.make:113: recipe for target 'devel/lib/team1/testCode' failed
make[3]: *** [devel/lib/team1/testCode] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:784: recipe for target 'team1/CMakeFiles/testCode.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [team1/CMakeFiles/testCode.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:796: recipe for target 'team1/CMakeFiles/testCode.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [team1/CMakeFiles/testCode.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:446: recipe for target 'testCode' failed
make: *** [testCode] Error 2
```

EDIT:

I figured it out, it was a stupid mistake on my part, I made a mistake on my CMakeLists and it wasn't compiling both files together, special thanks to @NathaOliver for pointing that out to me. And sorry for wasting your time on such a simple problem.

Comment: How are you compiling?  Sounds like you forgot to compile all the cpp files together.

Comment: You declare as `void size()` you define as `int size()`.

Comment: I don't believe that `RobotInfo.cpp` ever compiled with the code you posted. Can you try out `gcc RobotInfo.cpp`?

Comment: Show the full errors you are getting. There is no enough info. Also, this `static void size();` in `RobotInfo.h` but inside `RobotInfo.cpp` the function is `int Joints::size()`. It is clearly something wrong with the information you've posted it.

Comment: Sorry about that, made a mistake while copying the code here, the static void size() is actually static int size().

Comment: @NathanOliver, That was the problem, I accidentally was not compiling RobotInfo.cpp because of a mistake I made in my CMakeLists

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I made a mistake in my CMakeLists and it wasn't compiling RobotInfo.cpp together with TestCode.cpp, so when calling RobotInfo.h it couldn't find the implementation and would throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

Your .cpp is expecting to `return`:

```
int Joints::size() {
    return (int) info.size();
}
```

Your .h is a `void`:

```
static void size();
```

Your call is a `void` (and wrong):

```
Joints::size();
```

Note: Declare an object of `Joints` type, then call `size()` (and any other functions) on that object. Like:

```
Joints MyObject;
int size = MyObject.size();
```

Comment: `cannot overload static and non-static member functions with the same parameter types` this is what you get.

Comment: You are missing the point. Also, why *Your call is a void (and wrong):*? If this is a static function, then it is correct.

Comment: Sorry about that, I actually have the size() function returning int, but i messed up when copying it here. I should have triple checked it.

Comment: @mbsff then see the last part of my answer. This is how you should be calling `size()`

Comment: @KyleKhalaf, *Why don't you post the correct answer?* that is because there is no enough info.